# Proving uniqueness of solutions for the ODE f''(x) = kf(x).

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For the ODE $f'(x) = kf(x)$, we can differentiate $f(x)e^{-kx}$ to obtain

$$(f(x)e^{-kx})' = f'(x)e^{-kx} - kf(x)e^{-kx}=(f'(x)-kf(x))e^{-kx}=0$$

showing that $f(x)e^{-kx}=C$ and thus $f(x)=Ce^{kx}$, proving uniqueness up to a multiplicative constant, with different constants corresponding to different initial conditions. It has been a while since I studied ODE's but if I recall correctly there is a similar strategy for the ODE $f''(x) = kf(x)$.

Comment: Wouldn't both $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ satisfy $f''(x) = f(x)$, showing that the ODE lacks a unique solution?

Comment: You can construct a vector valued analogue as $f'' = f$ can be written as the first order coupled ODE ${\bf f}' = A {\bf f}$ with $A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}$ and ${\bf f} = (f_1, f_2)^T$ where $f_1 = f$ and $f_2 = f'$.

Comment: Also ... the claim of "uniqueness" is a little odd, in the sense that there's an undetermined constant $C$ in there. For $f'' = f$, you get a similar result: $f$ is $A \cosh x + B \sinh x$ for some values of $A$ and $B$. (Alternatively (and equivalently), it's a combination of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$.)

Comment: All these objections goes away if we add in the initial conditions in the problem statement. A correct statement is that the ODE $f'(x) = f(x)$ with the initial condition $f(0) = C$ has the unique solution $f(x) = C e^x$. Likewise the ODE $f''(x) = f(x)$ with the initial conditions $f(0) = C$ and $f'(0) = D$ has the unique solution $f(x) = C\cosh(x) + D\sinh(x)$.

Comment: Well uniqueness up to a multiplicative constant or with certain initial conditions - I thought there was a similar result for $f''=kf$, where one shows that all the solutions are spanned by $\sin\cos\sinh$ and $\cosh$ up to constants and depending on the sign of $k$. But I could be mistaken.

Comment: @Winther do you know if there is a proof of that similar to the one I wrote?

Comment: There are easier ways to solve this ODE, but as I said above if you insist on a similar trick then you can do it, but you have to work with vector valued functions and the matrix exponential. If ${\bf f} = (f,f')^T$ then you can show that $\frac{d}{dx}[e^{-Ax} {\bf f}] ={\bf 0}$ showing that ${\bf f}(x) = e^{Ax}{\bf f}(0)$. For $f'' = f$ we have $A$ as given above and you can then show that $e^{Ax} = \pmatrix{\cosh(x) & \sinh(x)\\ \sinh(x) & \cosh(x)}$ which gives the well known solution $f(x) = f(0)\cosh(x) + f'(0)\sinh(x)$.

Comment: Yes @Winther that's pretty much what I was looking for, thank you, it works for all values of $k$.